# PEP eight in wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, pep8

I use this code and (wx.SCRIPT, wx.ITALIC, wx.BOLD) are signed as pep8 warning. How can i Fix that?

`font = wx.Font(9, wx.SCRIPT, wx.ITALIC, wx.BOLD, False, u'Consolas')`

Comment: What warning? PEP8 has a lot of warnings associated with it.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this line though. You probably don't have enough whitespace around this line if I had to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I pasted your code into pycharm, it said that it `"can't find reference to wx.SCRIP, wx.ITALIC and wx.BOLD"`

if that disturbs you, you can fix it as follows:

```
font = wx.Font(9, wx.FONTFAMILY_SCRIPT, wx.FONTSTYLE_ITALIC, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, False, u'Consolas')
```

more on it: [wxpython docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Font.html)